# Why doesn't redirect work for scp password input?

Tags: ssh, scp, redirection, expect

I want to copy from remote box with `scp`, while the fact that each time I have to re-enter password is annoying. So I store my password in plain text and expect the following code should work

```
scp -Pport_num username@hostname:path_to_file local_path < passwd
```

After googling, I know this target can be achieved with the help of `expect` but I can't figure out why input redirection will fail.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scp` isn't looking for anything from standard input, so passing your password this way won't help.  Yes, `expect` can be used in a case like this, but you'd be better off authenticating via public key -- either with a specific password-less public/private keypair, or using an ssh agent in your current session.

So many tutorials out there, including:  [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. "scp isn't looking for anything from standard input". Then where does our input go? And where will `scp` look for input? Thank you again.

Comment: Your redirected file just goes into the "bit bucket", to nowhere, much as it would with the command `echo "Hello" < passwd`.  `scp` (or `ssh`) will ask for password if necessary, but do not take that from stdin.  `ssh` will send stdin to the command on the remote machine; I don't think `scp` uses stdin at all.